# Использование памяти и время исполнение скрипта PHP

Tags: php

Пишу проект на *PHP* с использованием *node.js*. *CMS* полностью своя.
Количество запросов к базе я снизил через memcache. Может возрасти до 26 запросов.
Очень переживаю за нагрузку на сервер. Насколько нормальны эти показатели?

```
Execution time: 0.00146 S
Memory usage: 365.3 KB
Database queries count: 9
```

Comment: Зря переживаете, *синтетически* у вас порядка 600 rps, что весьма хороший показатель (я не представляю себе машину, на которой тот же вордпресс сможет хотя бы сотню выдать). Я бы переживал за "CMS полностью своя" и "PHP с использованием node.js", потому что это флаги-предупреждалки о неверных поворотах.

Comment: Спасибо. Сайт сейчас лежит на самой дешевой впс от фаствпс. Node.js тут чисто запускается, вывод не ожидается, так что все нормально. По поводу "Полностью своя CMS" - код регулярно рефакторится :)

Comment: А потребление памяти в полмегабайта - это нормально?

Comment: Более чем, это копейки

Answer (score 2):

Решил все-таки ответить чуть подробнее.

Ключевой параметр веб-приложения, отвечающий за производительность - это RPS, Requests Per Second, количество запросов в секунду, которое обрабатывает приложение (и, как понятно, RPS формирует как сам код приложения, так и база данных, и сервер, и пропускная способность сети). Из единичного замера его не вынести никак, единственное, что можно представить - это то, что запросы идут последовательно один за одним и занимают вышеописанное время. В этом случае мы получаем RPS = 1s / 0.00146s = 685 запросов в секунду. Реальный RPS **не** будет равен этому числу, и **всегда** будет зависеть от оборудования (реальный RPS может быть как меньше, так и больше рассчитанного в зависимости от того, насколько хорошо внедрена многопоточность в весь алгоритм обработки запроса и насколько одни запросы могут тормозить другие из-за общих ресурсов), но само по себе число очень хорошее (хотя, подозреваю, у вас внутри нет особой нагрузки). Также надо сказать, что хорошим тоном считается отдать пользователю страницу в течение 200мс или 0,2с - это условие тоже выполняется даже с учетом расходов в плюс-минус 100мс на сеть.

Переживать за базу данных тоже не стоит, пока у вас записи исчисляются тысячами. Оптимизировать общение с ней - всегда плюс, но боязнь влияния БД на скорострельность обычно выше того, что реально стоит ожидать. Опасность, как правило, представляют джойны на больших таблицах и выборки по неиндексированным полям, но весь этот зоопарк обычно дает о себе знать только на больших приложениях. Пока у вас меньше условной тысячи записей - разница в скорости, скорее всего, будет в рамках погрешности. Еще раз - оптимизировать БД и кэшировать ответы **всегда** правильно, но зачастую это совсем неприоритетная ветвь разработки, и с кэшированием очень легко прострелить ногу.

Последняя ремарка - про самописную ЦМС и ноду. Есть такое общее правило - hardware is cheap, developers are not - даже самый серьезный сервак в месяц обходится дешевле программера. Пока вы распыляетесь на разные языки, вы (скорее всего) тратите больше ресурсов (причем не обязательно прямо сейчас - найти специалиста на замену становится сложнее), нежели бы все делалось на одном стеке технологий. Аналогично и про фреймворки - не стоит ими прененбрегать, потому что даже потреи в скорострельности будут компенсированы устоявшимися интерфейсами, поддержкой основного codebase и уверенностью в ее безбажности, готовыми решениями для расширения и многими готовыми решениями, которые нужны уже сейчас (то же кэширование запросов, например).

Comment: Спасибо громадное за подробный ответ. Большинство вещей знал, некоторые нет. Фреймворки не люблю потому, что увидел как их использует большинство. К примеру, берем, покупаем шаблон джумлы, на темплейтмонстре. И видим, 15 фреймворков в одном шаблоне, которые отдают страницу за 30 секунд. Я же, стараюсь написать такую CMS, которая будет очень производительна, понятна и гибка для меня. Она уже используется в моих 3х проектах, я считаю это хорошо. В общем, если PHP не умрет, то и моя CMS не умрет.

Comment: Джумла и плагины не имеют отношения к фремворкам

Comment: Все абсолютно верно в ответе. Добавлю лишь то, что писать на фреймворке - это иметь в проекте своего рода стандарт, который другие разрабы будут знать, а они, как известно, постоянно и приходят и уходят, а проект остается. И, да, джумла, как и прочие системы для контентщиков не имеют никакого отношения к фреймворкам, и я бы даже сказал к программированию в целом)